# implementation of a federated database for multiple tenants in spring-hibernate

Tags: hibernate, spring

This is my first post on this forum and am trying to make it effective enough for all to understand.

I have this problem on hand which needs an implementation for multi-tenancy. So, the basic workflow of the system happens as following -

- First the user provides tenant-id
- Based on the tenant-id, the application connects to the respective schema
- The application behaves as was implemented based on the tenant-specific data from the chosen schema

Can anybody please help me on how I should address this issue efficiently using Spring-Hibernate?

What are the feasible ways of doing this in terms of bean and mapping file configuration?

any detailed guide or even references to resources to check out is much appreciated.

--
Rajdeep

Answer (score 1):

Steve Ebersole (of Hibernate fame) has a [good writeup regarding multi-tenancy with Hibernate](http://relation.to/Bloggers/MultitenancyInHibernate)